# How to throw exceptions from Handler

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm building a RESTful endpoint that should throw an error if there is invalid data. Here's a simplified (and slightly silly) version:

```
getEventsR :: Handler Value
getEventsR = do
    mpage   <- lookupGetParam "page"
    let filters = case hasPage mpage of
                      Right val -> val
                      Left val  -> error $ T.unpack val -- Throw an error

     -- The rest...


hasPage :: Maybe Text -> Either Text Text
hasPage = 
    Left "This should error out"
```

1. Is this the correct way - a function should return an `Either` that will later be expanded to an error?
2. I probably shouldn't use `error`, right? What instead?

As a side note, I'd be happy if my thrown error would be sent also in JSON format.

**Update:**

The reason I've used the term "throw exception", is because my code looks something like this (simplified):

```
let selectOpt = case addPager [] of
                    Right val -> val
                    Left val  -> error $ T.unpack val

let filters = case addFilter [] of
                    Right val -> val
                    Left val  -> error $ T.unpack val

events <- runDB $ selectList filters selectOpt :: Handler [Entity Event]
```

So if it errors out on `selectOpt` I'd like it to short-circuit, and not continue with the rest of the handler.

Comment: What do you want "throwing the exception" to do? Crash the server? Return an HTTP response (like a 500 or 404?)

Comment: Return an HTTP response (e.g. 400) along with a message. (e.g. `{ error: "This should error out" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sendResponseStatus` to directly specify the response:

```
getEventsR = do
  mpage   <- lookupGetParam "page"
  case hasPage mpage of
    Left message -> sendResponseStatus status400 message
    Right val    -> ...continue processing with val...
```

The second argument to `sendResponseStatus` can be any type which has a `ToTypedContent` instance. This includes `Text`, `Value` and other common types. See [this page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.0/docs/Yesod-Core-Content.html#t:ToTypedContent) for types which have this instance defined by default.

**Update**

In response to your comments...

`get404` is defined as:

```
get404 key = do
    mres <- get key
    case mres of
        Nothing -> notFound'
        Just res -> return res

notFound' :: MonadIO m => m a
notFound' = liftIO $ throwIO $ HCError NotFound
```

`HCError` is a constructor of the `HandlerContents` type:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.0/docs/Yesod-Core-Types.html#t:HandlerContents

```
data HandlerContents:
    HCContent Status !TypedContent   
    HCError ErrorResponse    
    HCSendFile ContentType FilePath (Maybe FilePart)     
    HCRedirect Status Text   
    HCCreated Text   
    HCWai Response   
    HCWaiApp Application
```

An `ErrorResponse` has the following constructors:

```
data ErrorResponse:
    NotFound     
    InternalError Text   
    InvalidArgs [Text]   
    NotAuthenticated     
    PermissionDenied Text    
    BadMethod Method
```

So you can `throwIO` a limited number of errors, and the error messages are limited to `Text`.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question to better reflect why I used the term "throw exception"

Comment: For example, I believe `event <- runDB $ get404 eid` - knows how to short circuit, and send a 404 -- But I couldn't understand how to do something similar myself :)